# Undefined is not an object (evaluating _this.ref.method) in react native

Tags: react-native

I have 2 components:

1:Parent
2:Child

I want to pass some data from child to parent. in fact, I have a method in the parent component as following:

```
mymethod= (message) => {
console.warn(message);
}
```

in the child component I'm using this:

```
      <Parent ref= { (child) => {this.refs= child; }} />
      this.refs.mymethod(message);
```

but when I run that code, I get this:

> Undefined is not an object (evaluating _this.ref.method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is wrong. you need to do pass the method from parent to child as prop and call the method in child as and when required.

```
  export default Parent extends Component{
         mymethod= (message) => {
    console.warn(message);
    }
     render(){
       return (
       <div>
         <Child mymethod={this.mymethod} />
          <Child2 />
         </div>)
       }    
          }
```

you can access the method in child as `this.props.mymethod(message)`